# React-Images and React-Photo-Gallery Compile Error

Tags: reactjs, react-image

I am trying to install React-Photo-Gallery and React-Images to get a lightbox gallery.

I am getting this error:

Error in ./~/react-scrolllock/dist/index.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `/Users/anmareewilliams/Apps/anmaree/anmaree/node_modules/react-scrolllock/dist/Scrolllock.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `ScrollLock.js`.

@ ./~/react-scrolllock/dist/index.js 7:18-41

I am not sure what I did wrong because I didn't touch anyting related to the Scrolllock and I am seeing that the Scrolllock.js is in fact named dist/ScrollLock.js

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong so far.
React-Images is using an old version of react-scrollock (4.0.1 latest is 5.0.0), which might be a problem.